# How to convert password and salt into hashed password?

Tags: php, hash, passwords

I'm updating my PHP login script.
In my DB i store password and salt, but now i will only store a hashed password.

**OLD**

```
//Check if password matches
$check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['usr_password'] . $row['usr_salt']);
for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++){
    $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $row['usr_salt']);
}
if($check_password === $row['usr_password']){
    $login_ok = true;
}
```

**NEW**

```
if (password_verify($password, $user[0]["hashed_password"])) {
    $isAuthenticated = true;
}
```

My question is how can i create a new hashed password from the old password and salt?
Can i do this in MySql or should i write a PHP script?

**EDIT**

This is how i did create the password and salt:

```
$salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)); 
$password = hash('sha256', $_POST['usr_password'] . $salt);
```

Comment: If the old password was also hashed, you can't. The typical way to do this is migrate users *as they log in*, when you have their password in plaintext.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I see. I have updated my question with how i create the password and salt!

Comment: [*"...good password hashing is more than just sticking a salt at the end of a password and shoving it into the SHA-256 hash function."*](https://dusted.codes/sha-256-is-not-a-secure-password-hashing-algorithm) But the point of hashing was that you *couldn't* know the password, so you'll need to use the approach above (or remove the old passwords and get every user to create a new password).